# How fit a curve with scipy with restriction on the parameter range

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting, data-fitting, probability-distribution

I am trying to fit a GEV to some data using `scipy.genextreme.fit`, e.g.

```
from scipy.stats import genextreme as gev
import numpy as np

# Generate some random data
data = np.random.normal(size=1000)

# Fit the data to a GEV distribution
params = gev.fit(data)

print(params)
```

If I want to fit the GEV and keep the value of the shape parameter fixed (e.g. 0.5), I have only to do:

```
params = gev.fit(data,f0=0.5)
```

What I actually want is to fit a GEV and keep the value of the shape parameter within a range (e.g. between -0.5 and 0.5). I tried:

```
params = gev.fit(data,f0=[-0.5,0.5]) #Does not work
```

It is possible with scipy to specify a range for a parameter for the fitting?

Comment: I think this can be solved by designed your own optimzier method (the default is [fmin](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fmin.html)).

Comment: Thanks,

After reading the documentation on the [optimizer](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.html), it seems that it is possible to specified bounds:

_Simple bound constraints are handled separately and there is a special class for them_:

`Bounds([lb, ub, keep_feasible])`        Bounds constraint on the variables.

Specifying optimizer is easy, e.g.:

` params = gev.fit(data,optimizer='powell')` 

But i don't know how to include the bounds in the call? 
For instance doing this crashed:

` params = gev.fit(data,optimizer='powell', bounds=[-0.5, 0.5, False])`

Answer (score 0):

I have found some elements of answer on how to use `scipy.optimize.minimize` to do what I tried to do

I generate random data from a GEV and I am fitting them using 'scipy.stats.genextreme.fit' and compare the results that I got from `scipy.optimize.minimize` for 4 differents bounds:

- Bounds = unspecified (should be equivalent to None)
- Bounds = None (done explicitly)
- Bounds set to -inf to inf (which should be actually unbounded)
- Bounds set to the actual value that I want (shape:[-0.5,0.5], loc:[-inf,inf], scale[0,inf]

```
import warnings
import numpy                                 as np
from   scipy.stats    import genextreme      as gev
from   scipy.optimize import minimize,Bounds
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

# Function to be minimized
def fun(x):
    return -np.sum(gev.logpdf(data, x[0], loc=x[1], scale=x[2]))

# Generate a random sample from a GEV distribution
c     = 0.25
loc   = 1
scale = 2
data = gev.rvs(c, loc=loc, scale=scale, size=10000)


################################
# Fitting the curve using "fit"#
################################
C,LOC,SCALE = gev.fit(data, method='mle')
print('%12s'%'Using fit:','[%.8f,%.8f,%.8f]'%(C,LOC,SCALE))


############################################################
# Fitting the curve using "minimize" (and different bounds)#
############################################################
# Define the initial guess for the parameters
x0 = np.array([-0, np.mean(data), 1 ])

# No specifying the  bounds (default should be None if I understood correctly)
res = minimize(fun,x0)
print('%12s'%'Unspecified:',res.x)

# Explicitely using None
bounds=None
res = minimize(fun, x0, bounds=bounds)
print('%12s'%'None:',res.x)

# Setting -infinity and +infinity (~ no bounds?)
bounds = Bounds([-np.inf,-np.inf,-np.inf],[np.inf,np.inf,np.inf],True)
res = minimize(fun, x0, bounds=bounds)
print('%12s'%'-inf to inf:',res.x)

# Setting bound on the shape parameter c:[0.5,0.5])
bounds = Bounds([-0.5,-np.inf,0],[0.5,np.inf,np.inf],True)
res = minimize(fun, x0, bounds=bounds)
print('%12s'%'My choice:',res.x)
```

The outputs look like this:

```
  Using fit: [0.24802565,0.99147038,1.99752719]
Unspecified: [0.24803505 0.99151589 1.99750206]
       None: [0.24803505 0.99151589 1.99750206]
-inf to inf: [0.         1.74141644 1.        ]
  My choice: [0.15475374 1.42297545 1.97813723]
```

So we got results really close to expected value (0.25, 1, 2) when the Bounds are not specified or set to None, but it fail in the other cases (the parameter are in the specified range, but they don't have the expected value). Why?

A last note, if I used a shape parameter with a negative value, e.g. c=-0.25, "My choice" is now close to the expected values (-0.25,1,2):

```
  Using fit: [-0.24485102  1.01219881  2.01972737]
Unspecified: [-0.24486353  1.01221328  2.01976429]
       None: [-0.24486353  1.01221328  2.01976429]
-inf to inf: [0.           2.81041857  1.        ]
  My choice: [-0.24486356  1.01221433  2.01976554]
```